# gRPC erros in WPF .NET Core

Tags: c#, wpf, grpc

I want to create a simple WPF Core, gRPC project. This "code" works perfectly in my .NET Core Console app, however WPF seems to be something special.

## ***Proto File***

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "MyProtoNamespace";

package greet;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings.
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

## ***gRPC Server***

created a default template in Visual Studio 2019 (**uses .NET Core 3.1**)

## ***Console App (works perfectly)***

created a default .NET Core Console App -> added the Proto file from Server to Client and changed the **gRPC Stub Classes** to **Client Only**

uses: .NET Core 3.1

has following NuGets:

- Grpc.Tools
- Grpc.Net.Client
- Google.Protobuf

*code*

```
static async Task Main(string[] args) // works perfectly
{
    using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001");
    var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
    var reply = await client.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" });

    System.Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + reply.Message);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
    System.Console.ReadKey();
}
```

### ***WPF .NET Core***

created a default WPF .NET Core app -> added the Proto file from Server to Client and changed the **gRPC Stub Classes** to **Client Only**

uses: .NET Core 3.1

has following NuGets:

- Grpc.Tools
- Grpc.Net.Client
- Google.Protobuf

*code*

```
Loaded += async delegate
{
    using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001");
    var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
    var reply = await client.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" });
};
```

**PROBLEM**

I can NOT build the WPF app

errors:

> The type or namespace name 'MyProtoNamespace' does not exist in the namespace 'MyWPFNameSpace' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Where did you define the `.proto` file? What's the differences between the project file of the console app vs the project file of the WPF app?

Comment: @mm8 I defined my proto files in each of my projects (e.g. WPF has his proto, Console has his own etc). About Your second question: nothing, they are both client only and my grpc server proto has also the same content but it's server only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue is related to the `Grpc.Tools` package and the special build process of WPF applications. The `Grpc.Tools` package is responsible to compile the .proto file and generate the service classes.

The solution is to move the gRPC client instantiation into a separate .NET Core class library assembly (project). Just extract this code to a class e.g. `GrpcServiceProvider` in this new assembly. Let `GrpcServiceProvider` return an instance of the gRPC client. Now from your WPF assembly reference the .NET Core library assembly and the `GrpcServiceProvider` class to obtain the instance of the client.
This will fix the build error and also improve the application design.

Don't forget that `GrpcChannel` implements `IDisposable`. This means `GrpcServiceProvider` should implement it too and dispose its resources properly.

**.NET Core class library project**

```
public class GrpcServiceProvider : IDisposable 
{
  public GrpcServiceProvider()
  {
    this.ServiceUrl = "https://localhost:5001";
    this.DefaultRpcChannel = new Lazy<GrpcChannel>(GrpcChannel.ForAddress(this.ServiceUrl));
  }

  public Greeter.GreeterClient GetGreeterClient() => this.GreeterClient ??= new Greeter.GreeterClient(this.DefaultRpcChannel.Value);

  #region IDisposable Support
  private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if (!disposedValue)
    {
      if (disposing)
      {
        if (this.DefaultRpcChannel.IsValueCreated)
        {
          this.DefaultRpcChannel.Value.Dispose();
        }
      }

      // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
      // TODO: set large fields to null.

      disposedValue = true;
    }
  }

  // TODO: override a finalizer only if Dispose(bool disposing) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
  // ~GrpcServiceProvider()
  // {
  //   // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
  //   Dispose(false);
  // }

  // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
  public void Dispose()
  {
    // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
    Dispose(true);
    // TODO: uncomment the following line if the finalizer is overridden above.
    // GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
  }

  #endregion IDisposable Support

  private Lazy<GrpcChannel> DefaultRpcChannel { get; set; }    
  private string ServiceUrl { get; set; }    
  private Greeter.GreeterClient GreeterClient { get; set; }
}
```

**WPF project**

```
Loaded += async delegate
{
    using var serviceProvider = new GrpcServiceProvider();
    var client = serviceProvider.GetGreeterClient();
    var reply = await client.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" });
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I was stuck with this problem all morning

Answer (score 4):

Add this line in WPF Project File, file with extension "*.csproj", specifically in the tag <PropertyGroup> and rebuild:

```
<CoreCompileDependsOn>$(CoreCompileDependsOn);Protobuf_Compile</CoreCompileDependsOn>
```

It will look like this in the .csproj file:

```
"..."
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
        <CoreCompileDependsOn>$(CoreCompileDependsOn);Protobuf_Compile</CoreCompileDependsOn>
      </PropertyGroup>
"..."
```

Comment: more detailed in the video: https://youtu.be/HFF2gstZS1A?t=106

Comment: In my net6.0 wpf project, it works well.

Comment: does this work with publishing the app? When I add this to the publish profile, it fails to build stating:

'The target "Protobuf_Compile" does not exist in the project.'